# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n \left(1-\frac{K}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\log n}} \right)^n$ for $\epsilon>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is not a homework problem. It has come up in my research. I am trying to show that $$\sum_n \left(1-\frac{K}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\log n}} \right)^n$$ converges for  $\epsilon>0$. I have no idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: Comparison test.

Comment: Compare with what?

Answer (score 1):

Start by an asymptotic expansion of $\log\left(1-\frac{K}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\log n}}\right)$, that is 
$$\log\left(1-\frac{K}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\log n}}\right)=-\frac K{n^{1-\varepsilon}\sqrt{\log n}}-\frac{K^2}{2n^{2-2\varepsilon}\log n}(1+\delta_n),$$
where $\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta_n=0$. This gives 
$$\exp\left(n\log\left(1-\frac{K}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\log n}}\right)\right)=
\exp\left(-\frac{n^\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\log n}}-\frac{K^2}{2n^{1-2\varepsilon}\log n}(1+\delta_n)\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\varepsilon\lt1$. Note that $1-x\leqslant\mathrm e^{-x}$ for every $x$. For every $n\geqslant\max\{3,K^{1/(1-\varepsilon}\}$, the inner parenthesis is positive hence $$x_n=\left(1-\frac{K}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\log n}} \right)^n\leqslant\exp\left(-Kn^\varepsilon/\sqrt{\log n}\right).$$ Furthermore, $\log x\leqslant x$ for every $x\geqslant1$ hence $\varepsilon\log x\leqslant x^\varepsilon$ and $$x_n\leqslant\exp\left(-K\sqrt\varepsilon n^{\varepsilon/2}\right).$$ Finally, choose some $k\geqslant4/\varepsilon$ and note that $\mathrm e^x\geqslant x^k/k!$ for every positive $x$ hence $$x_n\leqslant \frac{k!}{\left(K\sqrt\varepsilon n^{\varepsilon/2}\right)^k}\leqslant\frac{k!}{\left(K\sqrt\varepsilon\right)^kn^2},$$ from which the desired convergence follows.

Answer (score -1):

The main term is of order
$$a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}\sqrt{\ln n}}\right)^n\sim e^{-\dfrac{n^\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\ln n}}}\leq e^{-n^\varepsilon}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$
for arbitrary large $n$, so the series converges.

Comment: I am sorry I am just not seeing why $a_n$ is asymptotically equivalent to the exponential.